# Adding tess-two library to an android qt creator project

Tags: android, qt, ocr, tess-two

I'm working on an android ocr project with qt creator, the goal is to use tess-two library for android.

I've downloaded the tess-two library and run the `ndk-build` command, after that I've copied the tess-two folder into my `android-source` folder which is at the root of my project. I've added an `AndroidManifest.xml` and a `project.properties` file which contains the line:
`android.library.reference.1=tess/tess-two/libs/armeabi-v7a`

I have my java class in `android-source/src` where I'm using `TessBaseApi` class to do the "ocr" work, after importing `com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI`.

The problem is that the compiler can't seem to find `TessBaseApi`.
Getting the error: package com.googlecode.tesseract.android does not exist.

I've also tried adding an external library by right-clicking on the `project name -> add Library -> external library` which gave this in the .pro file:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/android-source/tess/tess-two/libs/armeabi-v7a/ -ltess

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/android-source/tess/tess-two/libs/armeabi-v7a
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/android-source/tess/tess-two/libs/armeabi-v7a
```

but it didn't change anything. is there a specific way to do this?

[Tess-two link](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)

Thanks in advance.